# LWJGL Image Transparency not Working

Tags: java, rendering, lwjgl

In my .png file, some pixels are transparent, but they appear black in my application.

How do I make the black pixels not render?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable blending for the transparent parts of your image to actually appear as transparent.

Something like this should do:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: thank now it work corectly